# .Net Framework C# Web API HttpGet complex object

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman, asp.net-apicontroller

Good evening,
I have one scenario that i have a httpGet method with complex object and needs to call this from another .net project by passing Json object., Below is the sample.

### APIController

```
[HttpGet]
    [Route("GetName")]
    public async Task<string> GetName([FromUri]MyClass myClass)
    {
        return myClass?.MyName?.ToString() + "this is my method result";
    }
```

### Postman

```
    http://localhost/api/NameSearch/GetName?MyClass={'MyName':'TestName'}
```

I know this is very easy to achieve if i change the action from httpGet to httpPost., But this has been told that i am not doing any update within my api, so i should not use the Post.  Also i should not be sending this as individual parameter like ?MyName=''&MySecondParam='',etc., The request has to be passed as single Json object to the API.

Please kindly suggest if there is any option. I tried the above ?MyClass={'MyName':'TestName'} which is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why must it be a complex object? Looks like that object only contains a single string property. Couldn't you just simplify it to take a string instead of a MyClass?

Comment: For simplicity i added this as only string property, but there would be nested class.,  kind of  ClassOne{ property1, classTwoProperty }